# Get tag name/attribute name in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, tags

What's the way to get a tag name and attribute name in XML?

If I have a XML file like this:

```
<a>
<apple color="red"/>
<banana color="yellow"/>
<sugar taste="sweet"/>
<cat size="small"/>
</a>
```

And part of my XSLT file is as below:

```
<xsl:element name="AAA">
<???>
</xsl:element>
```

So what should I write in the `???` part so I can get the output like this:

For tag name:

```
<AAA>apple</AAA>
<AAA>banana</AAA>
<AAA>sugar</AAA>
<AAA>cat</AAA>
```

For attribute name:

```
<AAA>color</AAA>
<AAA>color</AAA>
<AAA>taste</AAA>
<AAA>size</AAA>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? And for the record, your example is not a valid XML file.

Comment: Is that the entire XML document? It's not well-formed. Can you show more context?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tag name:

```
<xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
```

Attribute name of the first (!) attribute. If you have more attributes, you'd have to choose a different approach

```
<xsl:value-of select="name(@*[1])"/>
```

Both expressions would then be used in a template matching your input elements. e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="AAA">
    <!-- ... -->
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @_Lucas Eder: `<xsl:template match="//*"> ` can be written properly as: `<xsl:template match="*">` . It is meaningless for a match expression to be absolute and in very few cases it consists of more than one location step.

Answer (score 4):

Output the name of an element or attribute using one of [name()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-name) or [local-name()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-local-name):

```
<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
<xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
```

Assume this document:

```
<root>
    <apple color="red"/>
    <banana color="yellow"/>
    <sugar taste="sweet"/>
    <cat size="small"/>
</root>
```

Then this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*/@*"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*|@*">
        <AAA><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></AAA>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces:

```
<root>
   <AAA>apple</AAA>
   <AAA>banana</AAA>
   <AAA>sugar</AAA>
   <AAA>cat</AAA>
   <AAA>color</AAA>
   <AAA>color</AAA>
   <AAA>taste</AAA>
   <AAA>size</AAA>
</root>
```

Notice that both elements and attributes are handled by the same template.

Answer (score 3):

**This is probably one of the shortest solutions**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="*/*|@*">
  <AAA>
   <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
  </AAA>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (your fragment wrapped into a top element):

```
<things>
    <apple color="red"/>
    <banana color="yellow"/>
    <sugar taste="sweet"/>
    <cat size="small"/>
</things>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<AAA>apple</AAA>
<AAA>color</AAA>
<AAA>banana</AAA>
<AAA>color</AAA>
<AAA>sugar</AAA>
<AAA>taste</AAA>
<AAA>cat</AAA>
<AAA>size</AAA>
```