# XSLT issue...CSV issue.?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to evaluate on each line of the CSV file if the value in the **parent_item** column occurs more than 1 time in the CSV file.  i need to output a Boolean to a new column - lets label it **parent_count**.  If the value in the parent_item column occurs 2 or more times in the CSV file, output TRUE to parent_count, else output FALSE to the parent_count field.  Can someone please help me if this can be done using code into the XSLT.

File will be converted to CSV from XML's.

Please help as i am new to XSLT.

**EDIT**

```xml
<AdditionalAttributes groupLabel="Custom Attributes">
    <AdditionalAttribute dataType="Decimal" value="" name="Standard Cost" dimension="$"/>
    <AdditionalAttribute dataType="Decimal" value="" name="Target Cost" dimension="$"/>
    <AdditionalAttribute dataType="Decimal" value="" name="Target Price" dimension="$"/>
    <AdditionalAttribute description="quoted" dataType="Decimal" value="" name="Active Cost #1" dimension="$"/>
    <AdditionalAttribute description="quoted" dataType="Decimal" value="" name="Active Cost #2" dimension="$"/>
    <AdditionalAttribute dataType="String" value="" name="Active Cost Line #1"/>
    <AdditionalAttribute dataType="String" value="" name="Active Cost Line #2"/>
    <AdditionalAttribute dataType="String" value="" name="Description"/>
    <AdditionalAttribute dataType="String" value="Off-the-Shelf (OTS)" name="Procurement Type"/>
    <AdditionalAttribute dataType="String" value="OTHER" name="General Posting Group"/>
    <AdditionalAttribute dataType="String" value="OTHER" name="Inventory Posting Group"/>
    <AdditionalAttribute dataType="String" value="PARTS" name="Item Category Group"/>
</AdditionalAttributes>
```

**EDIT Requirements**

I have a column **parent_item** in which the values are as such

- **parent_item**                   **parent_count**

  1. Row 1 :441-0230-001                   true
  2. Row 2 :441-0230-001                   true
  3. Row 3 :441-0230-001                   true
  4. Row 4 :441-0230-001                   true
  5. Row 5 :SP-SSD-80GB                    false

now the value in row 1 repeats 4 times for 4 records so the value in parent_count is true.
and row 5 value in parent item occurs only once.so parent count has false.

This is my exact requirements.Can you help me achieve this.I am very new to XSL coding.

**NEW XML**

```xml
<Item
   itemIdentifier="650-0107-001"
   itemUniqueIdentifier="IVI10144102348"
   globalLifeCyclePhaseCode="Production"
   globalProductTypeCode="6xx - PCBA&apos;s"
   revisionIdentifier="A"
   proprietaryProductFamily=""
   category="6xx - PCBA&apos;s"
   globalProductUnitOfMeasureCode="FA"
   revisionReleasedDate="2013-07-31T00:00:00-08:00"
   ownerName=""
   isTopLevel="Yes"
   description="Transceivers">

  <AdditionalAttributes groupLabel="Version Information">
    <AdditionalAttribute name="Version Notes" value="test" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
    <AdditionalAttribute name="Change Number" value="DEV-000130" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
    <AdditionalAttribute name="Version Shared" value="Yes" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
    <AdditionalAttribute name="Effective Version Shared" value="Yes" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
    <AdditionalAttribute name="Material Effectivity Date" value="2013-05-20T11:05:41-08:00" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
    <AdditionalAttribute name="Disposition Notes" value="In the Field =N/A- Does Not Apply; WIP =N/A-Does Not Apply; On Order =N/A-Does Not Apply; Finished Goods =N/A-Does Not Apply; In Stock =See Notes; In Stock Notes=Authorize existing stock until specified expiration 7/31/2013; Depot =N/A- Does Not Apply; CTO-Configure to Order =N/A-Does Not Apply" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
    <AdditionalAttribute name="Item Creation Date" value="2012-07-06T12:14:03-08:00" dataType="String"></AdditionalAttribute>
  </AdditionalAttributes>
</Item>
```

**XSLT CODE**

This is the code where i am adding column

```xml
<map:attribute type="internal" ref="id" container="Item">
    <map:aren>itemIdentifier</map:aren>
    <map:generic delimiter="false" name="parent_item" width="50"/>
</map:attribute>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can definitely be done using XSLT if the source format of your data is in XML. You can iterate over the tag representing a line in your future CSV file and then use an xpath expression with count to make the test you need.

From your input I will assume that we have the following (simplified for brevity) input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Items>
  <Item
      itemIdentifier="650-0107-001"
      itemUniqueIdentifier="IVI99999999999"
      description="Transceivers">
    <AdditionalAttributes groupLabel="Custom Attributes">
      <AdditionalAttribute dataType="String" value="OTHER1" name="Inventory Posting Group"/>
      <AdditionalAttribute dataType="String" value="PARTS1" name="Item Category Group"/>
    </AdditionalAttributes>
  </Item>
  <Item
      itemIdentifier="650-0107-001"
      itemUniqueIdentifier="IVI10144102348"
      description="Receivers">
    <AdditionalAttributes groupLabel="Custom Attributes">
      <AdditionalAttribute dataType="String" value="OTHER2" name="Inventory Posting Group"/>
      <AdditionalAttribute dataType="String" value="PARTS2" name="Item Category Group"/>
    </AdditionalAttributes>
  </Item>
  <Item
      itemIdentifier="SP-SSD-80GB"
      itemUniqueIdentifier="IVI10144102348"
      description="Transmitters">
    <AdditionalAttributes groupLabel="Custom Attributes">
      <AdditionalAttribute dataType="String" value="OTHER3" name="Inventory Posting Group"/>
      <AdditionalAttribute dataType="String" value="PARTS3" name="Item Category Group"/>
    </AdditionalAttributes>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

In addition we have small mapping files which defining the `parent_item`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<maps xmlns:map="http://my.namespace">
  <map:attribute 
      type="internal" ref="id" container="Item">
    <map:aren>itemIdentifier</map:aren>
    <map:generic delimiter="false" name="parent_item" width="50"/>
  </map:attribute>
</maps>
```

Using a simple version of *reflection* (`local-name()`) (see [Get tag name/attribute name in XML using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522245)) the following XSLT sheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:map="http://my.namespace"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:param name="map_name"/>
  <xsl:variable name="map" select="document($map_name)"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Items">

    <xsl:for-each select="Item">

      <xsl:for-each select="@*">

        <!-- output the attribute value -->
        <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <!-- get the name of parent_item attribute from the map -->
        <xsl:variable name="parent_item" select="$map/maps/map:attribute/map:aren/text()"/>

        <!-- if the current attribute is a parent_item execute the uniqueness check -->
        <xsl:if test="$map/maps/map:attribute/map:aren = local-name(.)">

          <!-- introduce local variable for easy test below-->
          <xsl:variable name="current_parent_value" select="../@*[local-name(.) = $parent_item]"/>
          <!-- compute the boolean column depending on the count of current_parent_item -->
          <xsl:variable name="parent_count">

            <xsl:choose>
              <!-- note that we have to compare > 1 (and not > 0) since an entry will ALWAYS find itself -->
              <xsl:when test="count(/Items/Item[ @*[local-name(.) = $parent_item] = $current_parent_value]) > 1">
                <xsl:text>TRUE</xsl:text>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>FALSE</xsl:text>            
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:variable>
          <!-- output the result of the uniqueness check -->
          <xsl:value-of select="$parent_count"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>

        </xsl:if>

      </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:for-each select="AdditionalAttributes/AdditionalAttribute">
        <!-- output the values of the remaining attributes -->
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/><xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will generate the CSV result file

```
650-0107-001;TRUE;IVI99999999999;Transceivers;OTHER1;PARTS1;
650-0107-001;TRUE;IVI10144102348;Receivers;OTHER2;PARTS2;
SP-SSD-80GB;FALSE;IVI10144102348;Transmitters;OTHER3;PARTS3;
```

If we use a different map file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<maps xmlns:map="http://my.namespace">
  <map:attribute 
      type="internal" ref="id" container="Item">
    <map:aren>itemUniqueIdentifier</map:aren>
    <map:generic delimiter="false" name="parent_item" width="50"/>
  </map:attribute>
</maps>
```

we will get this result:

```
650-0107-001;IVI99999999999;FALSE;Transceivers;OTHER1;PARTS1;
650-0107-001;IVI10144102348;TRUE;Receivers;OTHER2;PARTS2;
SP-SSD-80GB;IVI10144102348;TRUE;Transmitters;OTHER3;PARTS3;
```

Notes:

- The name of the map file is passed as parameter `map_name`. You will have to find out how this works for your processor. In case of `xlstproc` you would have to use
    xsltproc --stringparam map_name "map.xml" convert.xslt input.xml > output.csv
- The code still makes an assumption about the tag where the `parent_item` is located. In principle you could make this even more generic by also traversing the document for matching tags, but I did not assume that you need this.
- The extraction of the name of the `parent_item` from the map file is kept rather simple. You may want to add additional filtering if applicable.
- Of course, you will have to fine-tune of the output according to your needs. The generic approach of iterating over the attributes for output is just an example.
- This was an interesting task for me since it was the first time I used *reflection* in XLS. :-)

Comment: Thanks Marcus for your answer.I have new to this XSLT can you please help me out..I have provided my input...Can you suggest how to do this..??

Comment: Thanks Marcus... sorry for my late reply..I have updated my exact requirements..Can you help me do that..I will be thankful to you...Thanks..

Comment: I think you should update your input file accordingly. Since XSLT very much depends on the exact format of the XML it is essential to know it before I can adapt my solution. Frankly, I'm a little surprised since I cannot find the values that you added for the parent_item in your XML file at all.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply..i have tried to update XML inmuy question where parent_item is there..Is this the XML you want.?Is there anything else.?

Comment: Yes, it did become clearer now. :-) So the attribute that is to be checked for uniqueness is `itemIdentifier`. Is this true? In the required output the `<AdditionalAttributes>` do not occur at all. Shall I still consider them when I update my answer or shall I simplify it to the bare minimum required?

Comment: Yes itemIdentifier needs to checked for uniqueness...Marcus it will be better if you can consider it too if possible...so i can understand easily..

Comment: Maybe I should read the whole updated question before commenting! The last entry referring to `<map>` configures how you want the uniqueness to be evaluated, correct? So it has to be generic and not fixed in the XSLT code which increases the effort a little bit. Do you have to allow for several `<map>` entries? For my updated solution can I assume that both the `<Item>` and the `<map>` tags reside in the same input file?

Comment: I didnt understand your question..the last part..I assume that both the <Item> and the <map> tags reside in the same input file?What is same input file here???Yes i have created different maps for each unique column.Sorry for the confusion in my question.

Comment: The question is how we _feed_ the data into the XLST processor since it has to be aware of your Business input data `<Item>` and your configuration data `<map>` at the same time. There are two simple ways to do this: a) prepare an input XML file containing both pieces of information or b) have only the Business data in the driving input file and then read the configuration data from another file in the XSLT sheet.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply..Marcus..The process i follows is i have multiple XML files..and i run the XSL on all XMS's files and it convert in to single CSV file....I think i have used the second option ie have only the Business data in the driving input file and then read the configuration data from another file in the XSLT sheet. –I hope i am able to explain now. what i am trying to show..

Comment: Marcus.Can you help me with the solution..?

Comment: Yes, I can, but it will take probably until tonight.

Comment: Ok.No problem..Thanks Marcus.

Comment: Thanks Marcus..I exactly needed this...You are a star.:):)

Comment: Glad you like it! Could you make my answer your primary answer then, please? Thanks!