# Get all preceding and following siblings for a given node

Tags: xpath

I have the following XML snippet:

```
<root>
    <CharacteristicUse>
        <UseArea>Specification_Characteristics</UseArea>
        <Value>
            <ValueID>123</ValueID>
        </Value>
        <Value>
            <ValueID>444</ValueID>
        </Value>
        <Value>
            <ValueID>555</ValueID>
        </Value>
        <Value>
            <ValueID>777</ValueID>
        </Value>
        <Value>
            <ValueID>888</ValueID>
        </Value>
    </CharacteristicUse>
</root>
```

I want to be able to get all preceding and following siblings of the Value node which has its child node ValueID with text = 555

I have been trying to combine the following way:

```
/root/CharacteristicUse/Value[ValueID='555']/following-sibling::* | preceding-sibling::*
```

But, it only returns to me the following siblings.
Is it possible to have one single query to get the output as:

```
<Value>
   <ValueID>123</ValueID>
</Value>
<Value>
   <ValueID>444</ValueID>
</Value>
<Value>
   <ValueID>777</ValueID>
</Value>
<Value>
<ValueID>888</ValueID>
</Value>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is brute-force:

```
/root/CharacteristicUse/Value[ValueID='555']/preceding-sibling::* | /root/CharacteristicUse/Value[ValueID='555']/following-sibling::*
```

This includes the "UseArea" node also, not sure if you want that.

Or if what you want is just all the values that are NOT a particular value, then

```
/root/CharacteristicUse/Value[not(ValueID='555')]
```

is more direct.

Comment: Hi, your answer is perfect. The 2nd one where i do not want "UseArea". But, i realized by actual XML has multiple "CharacteristicUse" elements with multiple value/valueid sub elements. If I use the solution above, it returns me all siblings even from other "CharacteristicUse" node. But I only want to select the one from current node which has the 555 value. Any suggestions? i am marking this as answer anyways. :)

Comment: @user2957476: You may also want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740753/why-is-there-no-sibling-axis.

Comment: @ Marcus: Thank you for the reference article. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
The xpath looks like:

```
/root/CharacteristicUse/Value[ValueID='555']/following-sibling::Value | /root/CharacteristicUse/Value[ValueID='555']/preceding-sibling::Value
```