# Get an element from the text of its descendants

Tags: xpath

I have the text of all the descendants of an element in one line.

How to get the element `class="Block"` ?

I could find an element with the text of some one descendant, but in another element it can be the same.

1 - It is necessary to use the text of all descendants.

2 - I don't know which tags are the descendants of.

3 - I don't know the elements and descendants positions, they always change

4 - Can be different number of descendants

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="AllBlock">
        <div class="Block">
            <span>First text</span> <span>different text</span> <a>first link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="Block">
            <span>Second text</span> <span>different text</span> <a>Second link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="Block">
            <span>Third text</span> <span>different text</span> <a>Third link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="Block">
            <span>Fourth text</span> <span>different text</span> <a>Fourth link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="Block">
            <span>Fifth text</span> <span>different text</span> <a>Fifth link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share XML/HTML source sample along with current/desire output

Comment: @Andersson I updated the post

Comment: Will the `div` always have 3 descendants? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20358691/4742570) illustrates a brute-force approach which will do the job for that many, but might become unworkable if there are more.

Comment: @Vipz , do you mean you want to select `div` that contains concatenation of all descendant text nodes, e.g. `"First textdifferent textfirst link"`?

Comment: @jsheeran Different number of descendants

Comment: @Andersson You understood me correctly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To select node by its *space-normalized string value* ignoring innerHTML structure, try below:

```
//div[@class="Block" and normalize-space()="First text different text first link"]
```

Comment: @Vipz , as @kjhughes correctly noticed, HTML structure added to question differs from the one on image. Ignoring leading and trailing empty text nodes with `normalize-space()` might solve the issue. It'd be better to update question with *exact* HTML DOM structure